# Some options to YouTube api embedded player not being respected

Tags: youtube-api

I'm having trouble getting the YouTube api to respect some of the parameters I'm passing to it. The specific options I'm interested in are "controls", "modestbranding" and "start", but there are others as well. I've got a sample page live here: http://designdeploy.co.uk/yt.html

The full HTML:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myytplayer"></div>
<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var ytplayer;
window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
    ytplayer = new YT.Player('myytplayer', {
        height: 600,
        width: 800,
        enablejsapi: 1,
        origin: 'http://designdeploy.co.uk',
        modestbranding: 1,
        controls: 0,
        start: 403,
        fs: 0,
        showinfo: 0,
        videoId: '6KRJr7k6xns'
    });
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, it still starts at the beginning of the video, instead of 403 seconds in, and still shows all branding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the options you're trying to set are not direct attributes of the constructor argument, but are children of the `playerVars` attribute, like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myytplayer"></div>
<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var ytplayer;
window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
    ytplayer = new YT.Player('myytplayer', {
        height: 600,
        width: 800,
        playerVars: {
           origin: 'http://designdeploy.co.uk',
           modestbranding: 1,
           controls: 0,
           start: 403,
           fs: 0,
           showinfo: 0
        },
        videoId: '6KRJr7k6xns'
    });
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlmcdonald/Qmr49/1/) to demonstrate.